# Projective objects in abelian categories having non-trivial morphisms

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm trying to read an article about $p$-adic groups (based on the lectures of Joseph Bernstein), and I'm struggling to understand a certain argument regarding projectives objects in abelian categories wich goes like this:
let $X$ and $Y$ be two objects in an abelian category $M$, such that they are both projective objects and $X$ is a projective generator. Then $\hom(Y,X)$ is non-trivial.

If you could provide an explanation with as little categorical jargon as possible I would be grateful as my knowledge regarding category theory is quite limited.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you want to assume that $Y$ is nonzero.

But even then, this is not true in a general abelian category.

For example, take the opposite category of the category of abelian groups. Take $X=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y=\mathbb{Q}$. Both are injective in the category of abelian groups, and so projective in the opposite category. And $X$ is an injective cogenerator in the category of abelian groups, and so a projective generator in the opposite category.

But for $\operatorname{Hom}(Y,X)$ to be nontrivial in the opposite category, we need $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ to be nontrivial in the category of abelian groups. But there are no nontrivial group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$, since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion group, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free.

Maybe you are missing some assumption on the abelian category?